# Dynamic dispatch in Rust

Tags: rust

In something I'm working on, I have a "data store" object and a set of operations that can be applied to that data store. I'd like to be able to expand the set of operations easily and create alternate implementations of the data store. Inspired by the [modifier crate](https://github.com/reem/rust-modifier), I tried to take its approach, essentially to create a trait for the abstract (store, operation) pair, and then implement it for each concrete pair.

Unfortunately, I can't quite figure out how to tie the per-concrete-pair implementations to the abstract setup. Here is a "minimal" version of what I'm trying to do:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait Target: Debug {}
impl<T: Target + ?Sized> Target for Box<T> {}

trait Weapon: Debug {}
impl<W: Weapon + ?Sized> Weapon for Box<W> {}

trait AttackStrategy<T: Target> {
    fn attack(&self, &T);
}

impl<T: Target, S: AttackStrategy<T> + ?Sized> AttackStrategy<T> for Box<S> {
    fn attack(&self, enemy: &T) {
        &self.attack(enemy);
    }
}

trait Attack {
    fn attack_with<S: AttackStrategy<Self>>(&self, strategy: &S) where Self: Target + Sized {
        strategy.attack(self);
    }
}

impl<T: Target> Attack for T {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Zombie(i32);
impl Target for Zombie {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bunny(i32);
impl Target for Bunny {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct BaseballBat(i32);
impl Weapon for BaseballBat {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Knife(i32);
impl Weapon for Knife {}

impl AttackStrategy<Zombie> for BaseballBat {
    fn attack(&self, zed: &Zombie) {
        println!("Attacking {:?} with {:?}! Whack whack whack! Whew. That was close!", zed, self);
    }
}

impl AttackStrategy<Bunny> for BaseballBat {
    fn attack(&self, hopper: &Bunny) {
        println!("Attacking {:?} with {:?}! Swoosh swoosh swoosh! Dang, he got away!", hopper, self);
    }
}

impl AttackStrategy<Zombie> for Knife {
    fn attack(&self, zed: &Zombie) {
        println!("Attacking {:?} with {:?}! Stick stick stick! Oh no! He bit me!", zed, self);
    }
}

impl AttackStrategy<Bunny> for Knife {
    fn attack(&self, hopper: &Bunny) {
        println!("Attacking {:?} with {:?}! Stick stick stick! Yum! Dinner!", hopper, self);
    }
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
fn main() {
    let louisville_slugger = BaseballBat(5);
    let rabbit = Bunny(-1);
    rabbit.attack_with(&louisville_slugger);

    let cleaver: Box<Weapon> = Box::new(Knife(2));
    let brains_seeker = Zombie(17);
    brains_seeker.attack_with(&cleaver);
}
```

This fails with the error:

```
test.rs:75:19: 75:40 error: the trait `AttackStrategy<Zombie>` is not implemented for the type `Weapon` [E0277]
test.rs:75     brains_seeker.attack_with(&cleaver);
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can someone suggest a better way to do this, or a way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any guarantee that your `Weapon` have an `AttackStrategy<_>` impl for any `Target`. Thus the `attack_with` function could not be guaranteed to be *complete* (which means defined on all possible types it could take) – and unlike Haskell, Rust disallows creating *partial* functions.

Your specific problem will probably better solved with a [component pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) (the text is aimed at C++ coders, but is applicable here, too).